# Juniper WLA532 with SRX220H2

Tags: juniper

I've ordered a Juniper SRX220H2 to upgrade our firewall and was thinking about upgrading the office Wifi APs at the same time. Juniper manuals mention that the SRX supports > 4 WLA APs and WLCs, but it doesn't say clearly whether or not you can get by without a WLC in small deployments and just operate the APs directly from the SRX. Anyone know if that's the case? For a small office it would seem overkill to invest in a WLC when we only need a few APs to cover the whole office (including backyard and parking lot).

Comment: Engage your Juniper sales team for some time from their engineer. They should be able to clarify the performance and scaling limits of this setup, for example it could be license restricted.